# What says the output of autoencoder?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, pytorch, autoencoder

What is the meaning of output of autuencoders? Can we say it is the noise removed version of actual dataset and should it be symmetrical?

Answer (score 0):

An autoencoder learns a lower dimensional representation of your input data, from which it reconstructs the input in the output layer. If you have noisy data, this may lead to a denoised representation of your original data. Assuming your data contains no noise, an optimal autoencoder outputs the exact input values.